# DisplayImageOptions configuration conflict in universal image loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

```
    private void setImageloadConfig() {
        defaultOption = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565).resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true);
        configuration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .threadPoolSize(3).memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(IMG_MAX_SIZE))
                .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(IMG_MAX_SIZE)).memoryCacheSize(IMG_MAX_SIZE)
                .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13).diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(new File(IMAGE_FILE_PATH)))
                .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024).diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOption.build())
                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context, 5 * 1000, 30 * 1000)).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(configuration);
    }
```

In global activity, I have set `DisplayImageOptions`, but there is a problem, if I want to config `showImageOnLoading`, `showImageForEmptyUri` and `showImageOnFail`, how can solve it, because in difference issue. I want to set different image, but if I set it in specific activity, it will cover the global configuration.

The problem exists in code part2.

```
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565).resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.home_list_img_picture)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.home_list_img_picture)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.home_list_img_picture)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgPath,iamge_photo,options);
```

If I move the `DisplayImageOptions` configuration from global activity to specific activity, it's OK, but causes another problem. When I switch activities, the image component will flicker, which is OK, when configured in global activity, how can I solve this confict, any suggestions?

Comment: I am sure when I configure the options in specific activities,and switch activity,image component load the image from cache,not from the network,because it cached when first load from net.So it should not flicker,right?

Comment: I have solved this problem. Just set resetViewBeforeLoading(true)is oK.